# Property overriding with accessor

Tags: c#, .net, properties, overriding

I am trying to add a `private set` accessor to an overridden property, but am getting a compile time error:

`does not have an overridable set accessor`

I would add a `set` accessor to the interface and abstract base class, but I want the accessor to be private, which you cannot add to an interface or abstract property as it sets its access level.

An example of what I mean is below:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int MyProperty
    {
        get;
    }
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass : IMyInterface
{
    public abstract int MyProperty
    {
        get;
    }
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public override int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
        private set // does not have an overridable set accessor
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way around this? I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: I would just add a private field to return in the get.

Comment: You can add a `protected` `set accessor` in base class and override it. private is not possible

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That's pretty obvious - good idea. It worked :) Set it as an answer if you would like

Comment: @rhughes Added as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You can't modify the accessor in the inheritance chain. So better option would be just add a `protected set accessor` in your base class. that will allow you to override the implementation in derived classes.

What I mean is something like this

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    int MyProperty
    {
        get;
    }
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass : IMyInterface
{
    public abstract int MyProperty
    {
        get;
        protected set;<--add set accessor here
    }
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public override int MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return 0;
        }
        protected set //this works
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Nope.

There is no way to change the access level of a method or property in an inherited class, or to add an accessor.

This is the only workaround I can imagine.

```
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
    private int myField;

    public override int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myField; }          
    }

    private int MyPropertySetter
    {
        set { myField = value; }
    }
}
```